# iOS - Get Camera Roll images from ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I managed to get photos from `**ALAssetsLibrary**` with this code:

```
-(void)getPhotosFromAssetsLibWithPhotoFilter:(NSString *)filterAlbumString
{
    _assets = [@[] mutableCopy];
    __block NSMutableArray *tmpAssets = [@[] mutableCopy];
    __block NSMutableArray *albumGroup = [@[] mutableCopy];
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [PhotoLibViewController defaultAssetsLibrary];
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if (group != nil)
        {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
             {
                 if(result)
                 {
                     if (![filterAlbumString isEqualToString:@""])
                     {
                         if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]] isEqualToString:filterAlbumString])
                         {
                             [tmpAssets addObject:result];
                         }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         [tmpAssets addObject:result];
                     }
                 }
             }];

            [albumGroup addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]]];
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(retrievedPhotoLibrary:)])
                {
                    NSArray *albumGroupReversed = [[albumGroup reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
                    [self retrievedPhotoLibrary:albumGroupReversed];
                }
            });

            self.assets = [[tmpAssets reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        }

    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading images %@", error);
    }];
}
```

I use it like this:

```
[self getPhotosFromAssetsLibWithPhotoFilter:@"Camera Roll"];
```

This works great. But the problem is I am localising my app and other languages that is not English does not use `"Camera Roll"` as the name of the album. I get no images when I use `@"Camera Roll"`.

Is there a name to use that represents `Camera Roll` ? That will work on every device no matter the language?

Answer (score 1):

Please use `ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos` to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
 ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];


[al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll

                  usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
     [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
      {
          if (asset)
          {
             // .. do something with the asset
                  }
      }
      ];
 }

                failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {
     // User did not allow access to library
     //.. handle error
 }
 ];
```

you can use different source by replacing `enumerateGroupsWithTypes`.

Second thing `ALassetlibrary` is deprecated now so you should try `PHPhotoLibrary`.

Hope this will help :)